# How can i redirect port 80 to https in aws ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using  Amazon `ALB` with `TargetGroups`

I have ALB Listener on HTTPS which goes to `TargetGroup1`.

`TargetGroup1` goes to `ECS Service`

Now i want if someone come from port 80 then should get redirected to HTTPS listener on ALB. Is there any easy way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your performing ssl termination on the ALB you need your ecs to conditionally redirect based on the value of the header `x-forwarded-proto` added by the ALB (its value is either `http` or `https`). This variable desribes the request sent to the ALB and allows you to act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no answer and this is a relatively recent question, the answer is that this is now supported out of the box by ELB.  Add a listener on port 80 with an action of Redirect and HTTPS is now an option.

Comment: is it available on ALB or only ELB ?